# using data returned from promise in another fetch not working

Tags: react-native, promise, react-redux, fetch

I have a handleSubmit function that I have added two post requests to.

However, one of the post requests relies on the data returned from the first post request. I've attempted to access this data by setting it to a var but it doesn't seem accessible within the second fetch. Not sure if my syntax is wrong.. any ideas?

I believe this should be working but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Thanks!

```js
handleSubmit = () => {
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/resources', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: this.state.name,
        description: this.state.description,
        link: this.state.link,
        topic_id: this.state.topic_id
      })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.props.addResource(data)
      var dataId = data.id;
    })

  return fetch('http://localhost:3000/user_resources', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        resource_id: dataId,
        user_id: this.props.users.id
      })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.props.addUserResource(data)
    })

  this.props.navigation.goBack()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's 2 problems:

1. You `return` some code and then try to run something else. Your `this.props.navigation.goBack()` statement will never be reached because the function ends when it reaches the `return`. That is not your main problem though.
2. `fetch` is asynchronous. It means that the function handleSubmit will read the two first statements ("fetch resources" and "return fetch user_resources") and then when each fetch is finished they will run their `.then()` functions.

This means your `dataId` will be undefined and you need to wait for the first fetch to complete and to execute the 2nd fetch.

```js
handleSubmit = () => {
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/resources', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: this.state.name,
        description: this.state.description,
        link: this.state.link,
        topic_id: this.state.topic_id
      })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.props.addResource(data)

      return fetch('http://localhost:3000/user_resources', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Accept: 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          resource_id: data.id,
          user_id: this.props.users.id
        })
      })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.props.addUserResource(data)
    })

  this.props.navigation.goBack()
}
```

Comment: @sofiat123 did you try what I wrote?